# Why does the following sentence uses present participle "teaching" instead of present tense "teach"？

Tags: tense, verb-forms

> Several months ago, a trade association **invited me to** be its keynote speaker on networking and **teaching** people to be better conversationalists.

I have read the above sentence in a book. In my comprehension, it is **invite sb to do sth**, not **invite sb to doing sth**, so I have two questions:

1. How to understand the use of "teaching"?
2. Can I understand the above sentence as the following?(added a comma before "and")

> ... on networking **, and** teaching people to be better conversationalists.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's _invite someone to speak about doing some things_ (networking and teaching people to be better conversationalists) which is perfectly grammatical.

Comment: Do you mean it omitted `speak about`?

Comment: Parse the sentence _as a trade association invited me **to be its keynote speaker** on **networking and teaching people to be better conversationalists.**_

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Can i understand it as "to be its keynote speaker on (networking) and (teaching people to be better conversationalists)", the "networking" correspond to the phrase "teaching people to be better conversationalists"?

Comment: 'Networking' **and** 'teaching people to be better conversationalists' are two things.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thanks a lot! To make my question clear, I have modified it, can I understand it as "... on networking , and teaching people to be better conversationalists."?

Comment: ‘networking’ and ‘teaching’ have the same role in the sentence: both are objects of ‘[speak] on’, which is the only object of ‘invited to’.  Changing it to ‘teach’ would change that structure.

Comment: @AntonSherwood Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equivalent of *"do"* in this sentence is *"to be its keynote speaker"* , not "teaching". Therefore it is correctly written as "to be" and not "to being".

Networking and teaching is the topic of his speech

Comment: edited for correctness

Comment: Thanks, I think you are right, at first, i thought it was "invite me to teaching people to do ...", but now I have confused which is the subject and predicate for "people to be better conversationalists".